GROUP BY and calculate average
I would like to create a column in DAX where I calculate the average quantity sold. In the table I have the week number and the sold quantity on that specific week but in the additional column I would like to GROUPBY article number and calculate the average in of quantity sold in total.
enter image description here
thanks for help!
I tried to use GROUP BY and AVERAGE functions but got an error.

Here add new column using this DAX formula,
'avg qty = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Book1[qty sold]),ALLEXCEPT(Book1,Book1[item number]))'
for reference, check this picture,

